# allow variadic unknowns in function arguments

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a small helper function that will allow me to stop repeating this code 100s of times:

```
SELECT
    jsonb_strip_nulls(
        jsonb_build_object(
            'hello', 'world',
            'value', 5,
            'error', null
        )
    );
-- returns {"hello": "world","value":5}
```

However, when I try to wrap this in a function I get errors because the string literals are technically unknowns:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_build_nullless_object(VARIADIC anyarray) RETURNS jsonb AS $$
    SELECT
        jsonb_strip_nulls(
            jsonb_build_object(
                VARIADIC $1
            )
        )
$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

SELECT jsonb_build_nullless_object(
    'hello', 'world',
    'value', 5,
    'error', null
);
-- ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "hello" has type unknown
```

Since the plain jsonb_build_object handles un-explicitly-typed string literals just fine, I assume there is a function decorator that would allow me to do the same?

Comment: What exactly are you repeating a hundred times? Only the combined `jsonb_strip_nulls` + `jsonb_build_object` calls, or also the property names? In the latter case, it might make more sense to have a non-variadic function where you only have to pass the property values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to use the pseudo-type `anyarray` as the arguments always are texts:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_build_nullless_object(VARIADIC text[])
...
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=453e3808cd6d601876c8ec1597328ec1)

Note that arguments on odd positions are texts, so the whole array of arguments has to be `text[]`. SQL functions cannot have arguments of type "any" in contrast to some built-in functions like `jsonb_build_object(VARIADIC "any")`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work if building a jsonb object that has boolean or number values, etc.; it only works if all keys have text values. I should have specified that need, and updated my examples in OP to reflect that. If I add an additional key-value-pair into the DBfiddle with "value":5 then it breaks the polymorphism.

Comment: oh, just saw your after-comment; so it sounds like what I'm trying to do is not possible; its just that jsonb_build_object has an exception built into it that is not openly available.

Comment: Yes, you can create the *fully polymorphic* functions only in C as Postgres extensions.